# Using Astyanax library from Scala

Tags: scala, astyanax

I am trying to use the Astyanax library, but my language is Scala.

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started

I want to know if anyone has found any resources, documentation or examples of this library and Scala.

Basically I need to scan a large Cassandra table from beginning to end using Scala (and I can't use spark). The ability to scan the table in parallel is definitely attractive in astyanax... but so far I have not been able to use it from Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the library from Scala. If anyone is interested in this you can get a POC from here

https://github.com/abhsrivastava/AstyanaxScala